# cakephp: with saveAll(), imported (non-form-related) associated data not saving

Tags: php, cakephp, save

My question relates to pulling data from a remote source and saving it to a local database. With the `saveAll()`, the parent data gets saved correctly, but not the child data.

```
protected function _saveLocal($_rekeyedData) {
        //Set the invoice header and line items models
        if (!isset($this->LocalHeader)) {
            $this->loadModel('LocalHeader');
            $this->LocalHeader->create();
//            $this->LocalHeader->set($_rekeyedData);
            if (!isset($this->LocalDetail)) {
                $this->loadModel('LocalDetail');
                $this->LocalDetail->create();
            }
        }

        if ($this->LocalHeader->saveAll($_rekeyedData, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your data has been saved.');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Data load failed.');
        }
        debug( $this->LocalDetail->invalidFields() );
    }
```

In this function, I load the models, then attempt to `saveAll()`. A sample record looks like this:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [LocalHeader] => Array
            (
                [SOPNUMBE] => CR014076             
                [DUEDATE] => 2012-04-10 00:00:00
                [DOCDATE] => 2012-04-10 00:00:00
                [DOCAMNT] => 12000.00000
                [SUBTOTAL] => 12000.00000
            )

        [LocalDetail] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ITEMNMBR] => BASIC SERVICE                  
                        [QUANTITY] => 1.00000
                        [UOFM] => EA       
                        [UNITPRCE] => 12000.00000
                        [TAXAMNT] => .00000
                        [CONTSTARTDTE] => 1900-01-01 00:00:00
                        [CONTENDDTE] => 1900-01-01 00:00:00
                        [SOPNUMBE] => CR014076             
                    )

            )

    )
```

All that gets saved is the LocalHeader record. My hunch is that it has something to do with the `array('validate' => 'first')`. I think I need to do something separate like validateMany when using `saveAll()`, but I can't remember where I saw something like that or if I just made it up.

I've read many of the related questions in SO, but none of the offered solutions worked for me.

Any help is appreciated. Please feel free to ask if you have any questions.

EDIT:
This is the [header model](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1995441861) and this is the [detail model](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/2053924863).

Comment: (updated) Have you defined model relations? Have you defined model validation for `LocalDetail`?

Comment: Yes, I baked both Models. So, I have validation and the appropriate $hasMany relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that neither of those records exists yet. According to the docs

> If neither of the associated model records exists in the system yet
>   (for example, you want to save a new User and their related Profile
>   records at the same time), you’ll need to first save the primary, or
>   parent model.

You can read more [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto) with an example.

Comment: i think you are correct. i've been looking into that. thanks.